# SQL double join + count

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm struggling a bit on a SQL Query, any help would be nice !
here a schema of my DB : [image: SQL Database Schema]

I made a query that select specific rows in tables 1 and 2 with a join :

```
SELECT P.id
      , P.userId
      , P.title
      , P.content
      , P.date
      , P.imageUrl
      , U.username
      , U.permission
      , U.image 
FROM    posts AS P LEFT JOIN user AS U ON U.id = P.userId
;
```

now I need to add a new join on the LIKES table that would give me a count of the total number of likes for each post so something like : `COUNT LIKES WHERE postsID = posts.id;`

I tried many queries, here the more accurate of what I what I found but still not working.

```
  SELECT P.id
       , P.userId
       , P.title
       , P.content
       , P.date
       , P.imageUrl
       , U.username
       , U.permission
       , U.image 
   FROM posts AS P 
            LEFT JOIN user AS U ON U.id = P.userId 
            LEFT JOIN likes AS L ON P.id = L.postId 
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM L WHERE L.postId = P.id
   ;
```

Comment: What's the difference between count of the total number of likes for each post and number of all the likes on the post? Is this an sql question or a javascript one?

Comment: Your diagram contains a relation that does not exist. The `userid`s of POST and LIKES are not related. They are both related to (reference) the `id` of USER.

Comment: @forpas you mean likes.userId should refers to posts.userId ?

Comment: @Shadow probably just a miss explaination from me but yes I just want all the likes on the post, I just wanted to be clear but it's a pure SQL question.

Comment: I mean `likes.userId` should **not** reference `posts.userId` or vice versa.

Comment: Since you already know you need to add a JOIN to `likes` on `postId` and do a COUNT() ... what happened when you tried it? :)

Comment: I get a Syntax Error. My final query ATM : `SELECT title, content, imageUrl, userId, posts.id, username, permission, image, date FROM posts JOIN user ON posts.userId = user.id JOIN likes ON likes.postId = posts.id SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE postId = posts.id;`

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM L WHERE L.postId = P.id`.   No, you can't just place a *second* SELECT statement in the middle of a JOIN.  Use the `count` function in your initial select list, ie.. `SELECT P.id, P.userId, ... COUNT(L.id) AS TotalLikes FROM .....`.

Comment: Tip: In future, you'll greatly increase the odds of getting an answer by posting a *small* self-contained [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) - instead of an image.  For example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1da09177b3a6d9cebc97a3647cfb95ee